# EF Core list of Enums

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I'm working on small application with organizing hotel reservations in Entity Framework Core. I need to add information about number and the type of beds in every room. I was thinking and I decided that List of enums will be better, than storing it in separate table. But I don't know how to achieve it

```
public enum Bed
{
    Single = 1,
    Double = 2,
}

public class Room : IEntity
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
        
   public string RoomIdentifier { get; set; }
   public ICollection<Bed> Beds { get; set; }
        
   public int Floor { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }

   public bool IsFree { get; set; }
   public bool IsOutOfService { get; set; }
   public bool ShouldBeCleaned { get; set; }
        
   public ICollection<RoomReservation> RoomReservations { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to do so? I was also thinking to save it as a string like (1,2,1,2) and then parse it to receive number and type of beds in room. Much thanks for help!

Comment: A list of enum will store in a separate table by default. so a string of Id's parsed back into the list will be a custom serializer

Comment: Enums are stored in the database as integers.  Value Converters are used to translate between the enum type and its numeric equivalent.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Comment: @RobertHarvey That would be enough if I had one enum value but in my case I have a list of enums for each room object, I don't know if that would work.

Comment: I don't see how a list of enums would be different than a list of any other object.

Comment: Perhaps if you showed a bit more code?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've my Room entity, hope it would be clearer now

Comment: By not using separate table you gain nothing but problems - non standard change detection, inability to do server side query criteria on such "column" etc. Storing values in comma separated string is no better than storing dates/numbers in string instead of native data type. Nowadays database tables (especially when managed by ORM code migrations) are free (basically no cost), just use them and don't waste your time. I'm pretty sure the next question you'll send a few days after this will be "how to find Rooms having specific number and type of beds using LINQ and EF Core", with no good answer

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes but how I could manage this relation, I think it has to be tabel with only two records like Single bed and double bed and I woudn't need to have ManyToMany relation with this table to manage, adding beds to rooms or OneToMany and I will need to create a new bed object for every Room, that might be really tricky and cause many duplications in database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example with Object names made up, hopefully it helps.

In OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
        .Property(e => e.BedList)
        .HasConversion(
            v => string.Join(',', v),
            v => v.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList() ?? new List<Bed>())
        .Metadata.SetValueComparer(valueComparer);
```

You will have to create your own valuecomparer example below
for a list:

```
var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<ICollection<string>>(
                    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                    c => (ICollection<string>)c.ToHashSet());
```

Comment: Why would I need to have a `ValueComparer`? Working fine without one here.

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt Change tracking may be identifying the column change and doing a write when not needed without a value comparer. but  to be honest I have not tested without.

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to retrieve data where the value contains any of the values form another list or collection (example: `_context.Room.Where(r => r.Beds.Any(b => listOfBeds.Contains(b)))`. This will result in a "'b => __listOfBeds_3.Contains(b)' could not be translated".

Answer (score 3):

I misread the question... if you're trying to store a comma-separate list in a single field, follow richard's example... or handle it manually in your mapping logic if you have one.

The below answer is only if you're trying to use a enum instead of having a table, not if you're trying to fit multiple enum values in a single column.

---

There's a nice C# package called `SmartEnum` by Ardalis Steve Smith. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/ardalis/smartenum)

It'll allow you to have a strongly typed enum, but you can save it in the database as a string or integer or however you please.

Here's an example:

```cs
public sealed class Bed : SmartEnum<TestEnum>
{
    // static instances of the SmartEnum Bed represents the enumerations
    public static readonly Bed Single = new Bed(name: "Single", value: 1, isPremium: false);
    public static readonly Bed Double = new Bed(name: "Double", value: 2, isPremium: true);


    // example additional property of each enumeration
    public bool IsPremium = false;


    private Bed(string name, int value, bool isPremium) : base(name, value)
    {
        IsPremium = isPremium;
    }
}
```

The above example, the enum is backed by an `int` value. You can have it backed by a string by using `: SmartEnum<TestEnum, string>`. It supports implicit casts, etc., works well with EF, and you'll be able to "list" enums as needed.

Comment: Hmm.  [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) doesn't require any of this; you just declare your property in the DTO as an enum type, and Dapper does the right thing automatically (database field is an `int`).

Comment: @RobertHarvey oh sure, this is an alternative -- handles the problem at the domain layer instead.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that storing those values as string values would be best but other sugesstions are also very appreciated

Comment: EF Core also does that automatically and supports both storing (and querying) enum values as int or string in database, so no additional packages are needed.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm aware, like i said earlier... this is solving the problem at the domain layer, and it has its advantages.

Comment: how can one use this on the HTML UI select options?